# Trigger event after loading a div with content from an ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a scenario where I am loading html into a div in an ajax callback event. My goal is to append another div onto the freshly loaded div after the main content has been loaded. The main problem is there is a lot of html being loaded and I have to wait until the load has occurred.

Basic steps are as follows.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm
(
    Model.PostAction,
    Model.PostController,
    null,
    new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "contentLoadSuccess", OnFailure = "contentLoadFailure" },
    new { id = "reportBase_frmViewer", name = "reportBase_frmViewer" })
)
{
  ...
}

function contentLoadSuccess(ajaxContext) {
    showWaitIndicator(false);
    if (ajaxContext.Format == null)
        //If the format is not there then the server reponded but the an unhandled exception was caught and thrown
        //the content will be the user friendly version
        setReportContent(ajaxContext);
    else {
        if (ajaxContext.Format == "HTML") {
            //If the format is HTML then it is already in the result, inject it into the content container
            showWaitIndicator(true);
            updatePageNumber(ajaxContext.PageNumber, ajaxContext.TotalPageNumber);
            setReportContent(ajaxContext.HTMLContent);
       } else
            //Export option is used. The render link has a url friendly format to start the file download
            window.location.href = ajaxContext.RenderLink + "&format=" + ajaxContext.Format;
    }
}

 function setReportContent(content) {
        $("#reportContent").html(content);
        $("#toggleToolbar").appendTo("#reportContent");//<- Does not work content takes to long and will overwrite appended div
        $("#reportContent").show();        
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
     //This does not work either
    $("#reportContent").load(function (e) {
        $("#toggleToolbar").appendTo("#reportContent");
        $("#toggleToolbar").show();                
    });
});

$("#reportContent").on("load", function (event) {
    alert("This does not work either");
    $("#toggleToolbar").appendTo("#reportContent");
 });
```

I have looked into the .live() with load trigger but I read that it is being depreciated. Perhaps there is a totally logical way that I have not thought about. Or perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a timeout

```
function setReportContent(content) {
    $("#reportContent").html(content);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#toggleToolbar").appendTo("#reportContent");//<- Does not work content takes to long and will overwrite appended div
        $("#reportContent").show();        
    }, 200);
}
```